# removing directories with their path in txt file including space

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I wanna remove directories that their path listed in a txt file. some of these paths include space. for example this is my txt file contents, named rd.txt:

```
    D:\New folder\WOW
    D:\New folder (2)\here I am
```

so I can't use this command in batch file:

```
    for /d %%n in (rd.txt) do rd "%%n" /s /q
```

what command should I use?

Comment: If you want to remove all the content of file, you can use `cp /dev/null file_name` command.Try it.

Comment: @HeenaHussain, This clearly Windows... `cp` and `/dev/null` do not exist.

Comment: oh @Brad thanks for noticing...then how about `echo "" > filename`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /F "delims=" %%n in (rd.txt) do rd "%%n" /s /q
```

It does the job.

Long story short (you can use `for /?` to see the parameters), `delims` indicates what delimiters should be used, and default contains space character, so setting `delims` to empty value seems to be what you need.

Comment: excellent! thank you. unfortunately I have not enough reputation (15) to mark your answer as useful :)